# What is this technique on first load called?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to develop website using PHP, CSS and jQuery.
When I have visited many websites I have found a technique used over there. I am searching for that technique but I do not have a name for it.

When we scroll down to the page the first time after loading page, the elements looks like they are floating but the next time they do not look like that. For example please refer to [this](http://www.templatemonster.com/demo/55010.html) site. When we scroll down to the hot tours section they come in one by one the first time.

What is this technique called?

Comment: I guess `jQuery's lazy load`

Comment: @MubinKhalid actually lazy loads elements later, is that accurate technique? i am still on confuse and waiting answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in my view, it's the combination of `animate.css` and `lazy load`. Seriously, I don't know the name either, but if you want to implement that, head start here.
[All links that use lazy load](http://ressio.github.io/lazy-load-xt/demo/index.htm) and this is specific to [lazy load + animate.css](http://ressio.github.io/lazy-load-xt/demo/animatecss.htm)

Answer (score -1):

Reveal Animations When Scrolling - wow.js in most of the cases.

[Project Site](http://mynameismatthieu.com/WOW/)

[GitHub](https://github.com/matthieua/WOW)

Comment: you provide the example, i am searching the technique name. what this is actually called?